# Creating a dictionary in python from txt file

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

I know variations of this has been asked before but I'm still struggling with moving a txt file into a dictionary. The txt file has names and amounts separated by a ":" . I'm having issues with the strip function not removing blank lines. Another issue I'm having is if two lines have the same key, I would like to sum the values. I'm still relatively new to python so any help would be appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bloLD.png)

Comment: welcome to SO, u should paste code not images, add an example of what u've tried and what the problem is.

Comment: That file looks pretty broken to me. What's up with that?

Comment: The strip function doesn't remove blank lines. It removes whitespace at the beginning and end of a string. If the line is blank, you'll be left with an empty string, you need to skip that yourself.

Comment: E.g. `line = line.strip()` followed by `if line == '': continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple but not safe, there are lot of places where your program can crash but you probably don't care about that

```
def loadToDict(path):
    f = open(path)
    d = {} 
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "": # ignore empty line
            continue
        key, value = line.split(":") # decompose
        if key in d: # contains so add
            d[key] += int(value)
        else:
            d[key] = int(value)
    return d
```